# How to use nuxtServerInit in Nuxt as middleware

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I splitted my application into `server` and `client` one. I'm running server and using `nuxt.render` middleware in the express and I want to get my user/session/whatever in the nuxt storage. I've made a `store/auth.js` file:

```
export const state = () => ({
  user: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER: (state, user) => {
    state.user = user
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({commit}, {req}) {
    console.log(req)
  },
  async login ({commit}, {username, password}) {
    try {
      const data = this.$axios.$post('/login', {username, password})
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  },
  async logout ({commit}) {
    this.$axios.post('/logout')
    commit('SET_USER', null)
  }
}
```

Nothing happend when page loaded or action performed. There's [git repository](https://github.com/Iworb/nemvn/tree/07) with complete server and client sides.

**UPD For those, who looking for details**:
Make sure your `nuxtServerInit` function is in `index.js` file. You could move it like that:

```
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({commit}, {req}) {
    if (req.user) commit('auth/SET_USER', req.user)
  }
}
```

And `auth.js` file have no this function anymore. It works in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nuxtServerInit` action can only be used inside the store index.js file (or in another word where store is created).

So try to move your `nuxtServerInit` there.